# Expected Value Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, statistics

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. Is there any algorithm to find the next expected value given an array of elements?
For example, for A = [50,42,45,30,52], is there any algorithm to estimate the next element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An algorithm to generate the next element from a sequence, by finding a patter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466283/an-algorithm-to-generate-the-next-element-from-a-sequence-by-finding-a-patter)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list or a bag of sequence-defining functions, then it can be done. Otherwise, it is impossible to dynamically form a function from the data and predict the next element. Function-forming is not the problem, but there will be many (even infinite) functions that will fit a given sequence.