# Python how to get function formula given it's inputs and results

Tags: python, algorithm, math, interpolation

Assume we have a function with unknown formula, given few inputs and results of this function, how can we get the function's formula.

For example we have inputs x and y and result r in format (x,y,r)

```
[ (2,4,8) , (3,6,18) ]
```

And the desired function can be

```
f(x,y) = x * y
```

Comment: try using some genetic algorithms that evolves a grammar searching for the desired formula ;)

Comment: What if there is infinite number of satisfying formulas?

Comment: If you solve this i think 100 million people will be interested.

Comment: Isn't this just a system of equations? Perhaps you should take a linear alegbra or differential equations course. In any case, this does not deserve a python tag

Comment: I would say it's a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466283/an-algorithm-to-generate-the-next-element-from-a-sequence-by-finding-a-patter/36466936/

Comment: @DeepSpace one of the satisfying formulas is enough.

Comment: @sinabakh still impossible.

Comment: Another possible answer: `f(x, y) = (y ** 2) / 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you post the question, the problem is too generic. If you want to find *any* formula mapping the given inputs to the given result, there are simply too many possible formulas. In order to make sense of this, you need to somehow restrict the set of functions to consider. For example you could say that you're only interested in polynomial solutions, i.e. where

```
r = sum a_ij * x^i * y^j for i from 0 to n and j from 0 to n - i
```

then you have a system of equations, with the `a_ij` as parameters to solve for. The higher the degree `n` the more such parameters you'd have to find, so the more input-output combinations you'd need to know. Variations of this use rational functions (so you divide by another polynomial), or allow some trigonometric functions, or something like that.

If your setup were particularly easy, you'd have just linear equations, i.e. `r = a*x + b*y + c`. As you can see, even that has three parameters `a,b,c` so you can't uniquely find all three of them just given the two inputs you provided in your question. And even then the result would not be the `r = x*y` you were aiming for, since that's technically of degree 2.

If you want to point out that `r = x*y` is a particularly simple formula, and you would like to look for simple formulas, then one approach would be enumerating formulas in order of increasing complexity. But if you do this without parameters (since ugly parameters will make a simple formula like `a*x + b*y + c` appear complex), then it's hard to guilde this enumeration towards the one you want, so you'd really have to enumerate all possible formulas, which will become infeasible *very* quickly.